# Ruby on Rails - Displaying advanced search results in a Wice Grid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord, datagrid

I'm working on this real challenge for a week now and hope somebody here have a solution.

In a web application, I have a "Customer" model, which is in relation with a lot of other table like for example "Address", "Contacts", "Transaction", "Products", etc. Now I want to permits my users to search for customers based on a bunch of related models attributes, like the transaction type, the product expiration date, etc. Also, in a lot of other place in the application, we are using "Wice Grid" to display data, and we love the filters and sorting capabilities of this grid.

Even if it might work, I think it would be a bad idea to display all the search attributes in separate columns of a big Wice Grid because the grid will be 4 feet wide!

So basically, what I want to achieve is to have a big advanced search form containing the related models attributes where the user would kind_of "pre_filter" (scope) the "Customers" to be displayed in the Wice Grid. And in this results Wice Grid, I would only show the "Customers" attributes, so the user will be able to use the built in filters and sorting features of Wice Grid on those "Customer" attributes. But very unfortunately, we are unable to tell Wice Grid to use a particular subset (scope) of data. Well, I can't find how!

So any idea how to resolve my problem would be VERY appreciated. Even if your suggestion doesn't include Wice Grid, I will consider it cause I'm in a dead end.

Thanks a lot for reading

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) would be a good fit here. It allows you to do advanced search queries (including relations on a specific model).

I never used Wice Grid before, but by skimming through the documentation it should be possible to pass the result of the Ransack query directly into `initialize_grid`.

An example:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @customers = Customer.search(query)
    @customers_grid = initialize_grid(@customers.result)
  end

  private

  def query
    params[:query]
  end
end
```

I recommend reading the documentation for Ransack, it is very well documented.